# Built in directives not working on root component

Tags: angular, angular-directive, property-binding

In my app, the root component is `app-root`. When I set property bindings like

```
<body>
    <app-root [style.display]="'none'"></app-root>
</body>
```

the bindings are just ignored. I get no error either in my terminal or the console. The same happens with

```
<body>
    <app-root [ngClass]="'someClass'"></app-root>
</body>
```

These work fine with other nested components, like

```
<head-comp [ngClass]="'someClass'"></head-comp>
```

but not with my root component.

I have tried restarting the server and refreshing the page many times but issue is still there.

Comment: Where/How are you able to use the root component that you're bootstrapping? If you call it in its own template it would give a stackoverflow error

Comment: @eko I have edited my question to provide additional context. I am bootstraping the `app-root` component.

Comment: Oh so you're trying write Angular inside the `index.html`. I'm afraid you can't do that

Comment: @eko So how can I dynamically set the class attribute to the `<app-root>` tag? I thought of using `ngClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```js
export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') get class() {
    if (false) {
      return 'do not hide';
    }
    return 'hide';
  }
```

```css
:host.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a5tu81?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: When will `class()` be called? Will it be called if any member variable of the `AppComponent class` changes?

Comment: Hey, check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iwe4gw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. It should trigger in each change detection cycle.

Answer (score 1):

First, of all this is not right way to write even a single word in tag because it behaves as template directive or you can say empty box to be filled by app.component.html content,

The problem maybe  that the main element is not part of the component you are applying the style to

You can add this and it should target that component correctly.

```
:host {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

:host is used to address the hosting element (e.g. ).